Issue with Horizontal Collision Detection in Game Development
I'm working on a game and having trouble with horizontal collision detection between the player and block objects. The collision seems to work fine when the player collides from below the block, but not when moving horizontally.
update() {
    // Apply gravity
    this.velocity.y += this.gravity;
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
    this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
    
    // Update hitbox position
    this.hitbox.position.x = this.position.x + 50;
    this.hitbox.position.y = this.position.y + 10;
    
    // Check for collisions
    this.checkForHorizontalCollisions();
    this.checkForVerticalCollisions();
    
    // Draw the player and hitbox for debugging
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(this.hitbox.position.x, this.hitbox.position.y, this.hitbox.width, this.hitbox.height);
    
    this.draw();
    
    // Reset velocity.x for movement logic
    this.velocity.x = 0;
    if (keys.a.pressed) {
        this.switchSprite("runLeft");
        this.velocity.x = -5;
    } else if (keys.d.pressed) {
        this.switchSprite("runRight");
        this.velocity.x = 5;
    } else {
        this.switchSprite(this.lastDirection === "left" ? "idleLeft" : "idleRight");
    }
}

checkForHorizontalCollisions() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.collisionBlocks.length; i++) {
        const collisionBlock = this.collisionBlocks[i];

        // if a collision exists
        if (
            this.position.x <= collisionBlock.position.x + collisionBlock.width &&
            this.position.x + this.width >= collisionBlock.position.x &&
            this.position.y + this.height >= collisionBlock.position.y &&
            this.position.y <= collisionBlock.position.y + collisionBlock.height
        ) {
            // collision on x axis going to the left
            if (this.velocity.x < 0) {
                const offset = this.position.x - this.position.x;
                this.position.x = collisionBlock.position.x + collisionBlock.width - offset + 0.01;
                break;
            }

            if (this.velocity.x > 0) {
                const offset = this.position.x - this.position.x + this.width;
                this.position.x = collisionBlock.position.x - offset - 0.01;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

checkForVerticalCollisions() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.collisionBlocks.length; i++) {
        const collisionBlock = this.collisionBlocks[i];

        // if a collision exists
        if (
            this.position.x <= collisionBlock.position.x + collisionBlock.width &&
            this.position.x + this.width >= collisionBlock.position.x &&
            this.position.y + this.height >= collisionBlock.position.y &&
            this.position.y <= collisionBlock.position.y + collisionBlock.height
        ) {
            if (this.velocity.y < 0) {
                this.velocity.y = 0;
                const offset = this.position.y - this.position.y;
                this.position.y = collisionBlock.position.y + collisionBlock.height - offset + 0.01;
                break;
            }

            if (this.velocity.y > 0) {
                this.velocity.y = 0;
                const offset = this.position.y - this.position.y + this.height;
                this.position.y = collisionBlock.position.y - offset - 0.01;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

I've also tried creating a hitbox for the player object, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. The problem seems to occur specifically when moving horizontally. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Could you describe the debugging you have tried? And can the  player come from above the object? What happens if so?

Hey thanks for the response but I fixed it , not sure if I wasn't updating the players httbox position, or the collision with the bottom of the player and the top of the block. But it worked lol I don't know what I did hahahaha
